# file not found exception running specflow test with codedui in visualstudio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I've been searching all morning for an answer online to this and I have tried a lot of the suggestions though all solutions seem to be for visual studio 2010 and I am running 2013 premium edition, I can't see anyone with the same problem.

I have premium VS 2013, I installed SpecFlow v1.9 through the extension manager and added the SpecFlow nuget package.  I have created a CodedUI test project and added a feature file, some recorded codedui steps and a stepdef file. Nothing is complaining and it all looks like it should work.  I have added : 
`<unitTestProvider name="MsTest"/>`
to my App.config so I can run it from the test explorer in visual studio. I eventually want to run the tests via MTM but I will deal with that when I get this to work!

I have built and it is all happy so I go to test explorer and I can see my test so I right click, run the test.  It fails with the following error, it does get to my Given step when I debug and falls over trying to open my application.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I can not find the reference above when I have looked to add it to my project references, there is a similar one but it breaks some of my other references when I add it.  I also had a look at my registry files and the path it is referring to does not exist for me to edit it.  From what I have read codedui doesn't work nicely with specflow without a dll file. All references to this fix seem to be for vs 2010 and require that I copy a dll to my specflow source folder.  I installed specflow from visual studio so I don't have a program files folder for it so I came to a bit of a sticking point with that solution.

Does anyone have specflow working with visual studio 2013 and a codedui test project?  Am I missing a set up step?  Or is this genuinely to do with my registry files / references.  The error is confusing as I don't see why it is trying to find that reference especially when I can't find that reference anywhere when I try to find it manually. I'd be interested to know if you have had this error and managed to resolve it or if you could explain your set up steps so I can check I did not miss anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Your specflow will be installed in an extension folder. My advice would be to install everything from void tools and then search for techtalk.specflow.dll and then put the dll from the 2010 fix into the folder that the extension is installed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might be missing references to some of the required dlls. I just finished testing a test created using a Specflow, codedUI test project on my MS Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and it worked just fine.

Here are the steps which I followed:

1. Created a class library project.
2. Added reference to Specflow 1.9 from Extensions and Updates.
3. Added reference to Specflow CodedUI Attribute Generator (Install-Package SpecFlow.CodedUI -Version 1.0.0.23).
4. Added references to required libraries required for CodedUI and Test Tools to the project. See below the references I added.

   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.ExtensionUtilities
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
5. Added a separate CodedUI project to solution and added references of this project to the class library project.
6. Create a new Specflow feature file with some test and create step for it in step definition and reference to the function you created or recorded in the CodedUI project in the step definition.
7. Run the Specflow test from Test Explorer. It should work fine.

Note: The above steps should work just fine if you will create CodedUI project instead of a Class library project.

Comment: thank you, I created the solution, added the references and then copied all of the dlls it created into my solution and it is now running the tests from test explorer. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It was really helpful Iain, my reputation score isn't high enough yet so it is complaining at me when I try to upvote it but I will come back to it when my score improves, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Mark the test class with the `CodedUITest` attribute.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. I had selenium tests but needed to add some interactions with a desktop client app. After adding the view for the desktop client controls using the Coded UI libraries I got the error trying to access the controls. Well, my test classes were all marked as `[TestClass]` instead of `[CodedUITest]` Correcting that resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error message even though I had all the .dll's referenced correctly.
The solution for me was to regenerate the feature files.
(right click project and select "regenerate feature files")

Leaving this answer in case it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue today, not with specflow but 2013 build controller and agent and codedui tests.
The solution was to install VS2013 Update 5 https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs